# Insert Amazon dataset to Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to insert a dataset of Amazon products to Magento 2? 
The Amazon dataset file is in json format. 
How could this be done?

Comment: Not sure it works or not https://www.boostmyshop.com/amazon-m2-extension.html